# Comparing mysql data with folder files

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if there are any image record in my database that is not in my folder of images, but I cant seem to find a way to do this and I dont know why, I made this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT imagen FROM galerias", $dbh);
$flag = true;
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $directorio = opendir("../galeria/programas"); 
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio))     {   
            if($archivo == $row2["imagen"]){
                $flag = false;
            }       
    }   
     if ($flag) {
                echo "IM NOT IN THE FOLDER  ".$row2["imagen"]."<br>";
            } 
}


?>
```

It's only load one record only..

Comment: Try [file_exists](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: I need to put the $flag variable in true at the top of the while!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistakes is on the $flag, you did not reset the $flag after each check. So if there is one file that equals to the one on the DB, which makes the $flag false, the rest will be considered equals since $flag will be always false after that.

And it is better using strcmp for comparing string rather use "==". It is more binary safe.